# Define moving direction javascript (Android device)

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am writing PhoneGap application, and use swipe and scroll on one view. For scroll I use native scroll (I have tried to use iScroll, but there are many inputs in my view, so the better solution that I found it is a native scroll). For defining direction of moving I am gathering first 10 touchmove events in array and check clientX and clienY values and than define average value. And all should be good, but in Android touchmove event does not work is scroll view without preventDefault(). So, according this issue, I use preventDefault() for first ten touchmove events and than depending on direction continue use preventDefault() and make swipe, or don't use preventDefault() and make scroll. But when I make scroll nothing happens(. There is an example:

```
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
var arr = [];
var ev = document.createEvent('UIEvent');
var evEnd = document.createEvent('UIEvent');
var evCancel = document.createEvent('UIEvent');
var flag = false;
ev.initUIEvent("touchstart", true, true);
evEnd.initUIEvent("touchend", true, true);
evCancel.initUIEvent("touchcancel", true, true);
list.addEventListener('touchstart', startMove, false)
list.addEventListener('touchend', endMove, false)
function startMove(e){
    list.addEventListener('touchmove', move, false)
}
function move(e){
   if(flag){
     return;
   }
    e.preventDefault();
    arr.push(e);
    if(arr.length>10){
       flag = true;
       list.dispatchEvent(evEnd);
       list.dispatchEvent(evCancel);
       list.dispatchEvent(ev);
       return;
    }
}
function endMove(e){
    list.removeEventListener('touchmove', move, false)
    list.removeEventListener('touchend', endMove, false)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tnqHQ/17/